# Generalisation of Absolute Deviation and Least Squares Deviation: Statistical Use?

Tags: least-squares, least-absolute-deviations

[This linked answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451064/285446) defines Least Absolute Deviation (LAD) and Least Squares Deviation (LSD), as follows:

$$ LAD = \Sigma^n_{i=1} |y_i-f(x_i)| $$

And:

$$ LSD = \Sigma^n_{i=1} (y_i-f(x_i))^2 $$

Since taking the absolute value makes no difference to squaring, we can generalise both definitions as follows. Define:

$$ LD_r = \Sigma^n_{i=1} |y_i-f(x_i)|^r $$

Then we get $LAD = LD_1$ and $LSD = LD_2$. The question: are there statistical uses for $LD_r$ where $r \notin \{1, 2\}$?

For example, is there any reason to use:

$$ LD_{0.5} = \Sigma^n_{i=1} \sqrt{|y_i-f(x_i)|} $$

Note: I suspect that what I define as $LD_r$ probably has some standard name in statistics and I'm happy to learn what that is.

Comment: First, you may be interested in a post of mine on the square root of absolute deviation: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/73396/73930. Second, what you’re noticing is the relationship to $L^p$ norms, which would be the standard terminology for what you call $LD_r$. As the linked post shows, you can do pretty much whatever you want, but not all of it (such as the square root of absolute deviation) has such an obvious use. If you start reading about $L^p$ norms, you’ll see a lot of talk about integrals and even this “Lebesgue” integral. Just think of them as continuous sums.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean ?